# HEX to HSL convert javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, string-parsing, hsl

Hello I'm trying to create HEX to HSL converter function. I know that at first I should convert HEX to RGB and then from RGB to HSL. I've done so using some script from StackOverflow. S and L is working correctly but H (hue) is not. I do not know why, here's my code:

```
toHSL: function(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);

    var r = parseInt(result[1], 16);
    var g = parseInt(result[2], 16);
    var b = parseInt(result[3], 16);

    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    } else {
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max) {
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    s = s*100;
    s = Math.round(s);
    l = l*100;
    l = Math.round(l);

    var colorInHSL = 'hsl(' + h + ', ' + s + '%, ' + l + '%)';
    $rootScope.$emit('colorChanged', {colorInHSL});
```

When the input is `#ddffdd`

then the output is `hsl(0.3333333333333333, 100%, 93%)`

but should be `hsl(120, 100%, 93%)`.

Comment: This is quite old; however, since I stumbled upon it... here is a regex to account for shorthand and alpha layers: `#([a-f\d]{1,2}){3,4}` https://regexr.com/7foj6

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You forgot to multiply the hue by 360.

```
s = s*100;
s = Math.round(s);
l = l*100;
l = Math.round(l);
h = Math.round(360*h);

var colorInHSL = 'hsl(' + h + ', ' + s + '%, ' + l + '%)';
```